# Is it bad practice to allocate space for a function and then deleting the space from within the function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am currently trying to learn best practice C++ and thought of a way where function with returntype float deletes itself after having allocated space in memory. Can this lead to problems and is it best practice to do it like this?

```
class c_player
{
public:
    c_player();
    ~c_player();

    float* _getColor(void);

private:
    byte color[3] = {255, 0, 0};
};

float* c_player::_getColor() {
    float col[3];
    col[0] = c_player::color[0] / 255.0;
    col[1] = c_player::color[1] / 255.0;
    col[2] = c_player::color[2] / 255.0;
    return col;
    delete c_player::_getColor();
}
```

Also: will the float col[3] array be deleted after the function is terminated?
And,does this even make any sense :D

Comment: Do note that nothing after `return` gets executed.

Comment: To say it is "bad" is only mild.

Comment: but it doesn't show any warnings in vs

Comment: @OliverTworkowski You can crash your computer without getting a warning.

Comment: `float col[3]` followed by `return col` is a bad practice by itself.

Comment: `float col[3]` is automatically allocated. It cannot be deleted. It also cannot be returned from a function because it will automatically be destroyed when it goes out of scope at the end of the function. A decent compiler with the warning level turned up a bit will point out you can't return references to an automatic allocation.

Comment: `delete c_player::_getColor();` will never run (explained above). If it did, it would attempt to `delete` an allocation that is not `delete`able AND no is no longer valid. It's already gone. Plus it would result in uncontrolled recursion. Every call to `_getColor` would call `_getColor`.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz There's nothing unclear about this question though. It's simply wrong (and has no point fair enough). OP is just mistaken on how allocation / deallocation works.

Comment: @SombreroChicken It's unclear in the sense that there's no direction this code is going, and no real goal to achieve. I can't recommend anything here, as it stands. The OP even said it himself; *does this even make any sense* - but even that is hard to answer, as we don't know what and/or why was attempted in the first place.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz It is apparent that OP wants to free the `col[]` memory after the function returns. They expressed it in the only way they knew how (delete the memory after returning.)

Comment: @OliverTworkowski, have some patience. Getting upset about criticism doesn't help you.

Comment: @RSahu I dont know what criticism means to you. But by saying to a beginner that the code has no direction and has no goal is far away from constructive criticism.

Comment: I don't understand.  How does one allocate memory space for a function?  Normally, OS specific calls would need to be made to remove code from memory or reload.  Usually, code is always present (if not in memory, then on the storage device).  There have been times in the world of embedded systems that I've wanted to remove a function from memory. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this won't work. Because of the `return` statement the `delete` will never happen. Furthermore you should never `delete` memory that hasn't been allocated with `new`.

Actually, just don't use `new`/`delete` at all and start using `std::vector` and `std::array` in this case.

```
#include <array>

class c_player
{
public:
    c_player();
    ~c_player();

    std::array<float, 3> _getColor(void);

private:
    std::array<byte, 3> color = {255, 0, 0};
};

std::array<float, 3> c_player::_getColor() {
    std::array<float, 3> col;
    col[0] = c_player::color[0] / 255.0;
    col[1] = c_player::color[1] / 255.0;
    col[2] = c_player::color[2] / 255.0;
    return col;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Problems that I see in `c_player::_getColor()`.

1. Dangling pointer

   The array of `float`s, `col`, is function local variable. It does not live after the function returns. The returned pointer becomes a dangling pointer in the calling function. Dereferencing the pointer in the calling function causes undefined behavior.
2. `delete`-ing the pointer

   First of all, the last statement in the function is never going to be executed. That's the good news. You can delete that line and your program won't behave any differently.

   If it were to be executed, there will be more problems. You can `delete` a pointer only it was allocated using `new`. Since you don't have any such pointer, your program would have another point that would trigger undefined behavior.
3. `const` qualification

   It's better to make all the *get* member functions to be `const` member functions. Since you are not changing any of the member variables of the object in the function, you should make it a `const` member function.

   ```
   float* _getColor() const; // void is unnecessary.
   ```
4. You don't need the `c_player::` prefix to access the member variables of the class. You can use:

   ```
   col[0] = color[0] / 255.0;
   col[1] = color[1] / 255.0;
   col[2] = color[2] / 255.0;
   ```
5. Use a `struct`, a `std::array`, or a `std::tuple` return the color value to prevent the problems.

   ```
   std::tuple<float, float, float>  _getColor() const;
   ```

   The function can be implemented cleanly as:

   ```
   std::tuple<float, float, float> c_player::_getColor() const
   {
       float r = color[0] / 255.0;
       float g = color[1] / 255.0;
       float b = color[2] / 255.0;
       return {r, g, b};
   }
   ```

Comment: And even if the C-style array was allocated with `float* col = new float[3];`, it ought to have been destructed with `delete[]`.  (But `vector<float>`, `tuple<float,float,float>`, or `array<float,3>` are all better choices anyway.)

Comment: Thanks! Thats extremely helpful :)